API Gateway with no auth setting keeps returning Missing Authentication Token to Postman
I set up a simple http put gateway on AWS, with no authentication required (keeping it simple for now)
From AWS
From AWS
api gateway connects to a simple lambda function, and the connections work great when it's called from a python script on a Linux server (requests.put("https....."). However, from Postman and curl, I keep getting "Missing Authentication Token" so not sure why that error is coming back for those two other messages
curl -X POST https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Testing -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"hello": "yo"}'
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
About the only Postman/API Gateway help I could find dealt with api's requiring authentication.  Anything in the api gateway, or Postman/curl calls I should look for?
from Postman
Called api from python script (requests.put("https..."), success. From Curl and Postman, "Missing Authentication Token"

if you api gateway is set to PUT then i think you need to send PUT in curl
curl -X PUT https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Testing -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"hello": "yo"}'
you are doing POST request

Thanks, Nabin!  That mistake was so obvious, I missed it.  Did the POST in both Postman and the curl, as you saw.

we all are humans , i had done the same mistake at times, i am glad that you could resolve it.
